# Post data from one controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a mvc  application. I want to post 2 string from my controller to another controller in controller. Is it possible?

Comment: It is, but if you have a method shared between two controllers, you have a method that should be extracted to a class that two controllers can call.

Answer (score 0):

You can target any controller action from your form input in order to POST a string. If you want to pass a string or object from controller to controller you can use sessions or alternatively a database.

Additionally if you want to pass strings or objects between action methods in the same controller you can use the TempData collection as well.

Comment: what if my target controller located in another project? it is published and i have an url that i want to post data

Comment: Typically it is not a good idea to allow one site to post data to another site. This is often referred to as a cross site scripting attack. However that does not mean you cannot point your form at the other full site URL/controller/action method but I would strongly urge you to use some sort of verification code between sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use TempData for that like...

```
public ActionResult Sample1()
{

    TempData["Test"] = "Test1"
    return RedirectToAction("Sample2");
}

public ActionResult Sample2()
{
    var test= TempData["Test"] as string

    return View( test);
}
```